# Determine loop control based on last row

Tags: excel, vba

This code stops part way through the column even though data exist further down with no blank cells in between.

```vb
Dim LastcRow, LastqRow, lastdtyperow, lastdqtyrow, lastqtyperow
Dim Dst
Dim Foot
Dim c
Dim cRange As Range
'defines sheets for ease of use and less confusion
Dim dataentry As Worksheet, quote1 As Worksheet
Dim typ As Range
    
Set dataentry = Sheets("Data Entry")
Set quote1 = Sheets("Quote")
LastcRow = Sheets("Data Entry").Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row
LastqRow = Sheets("Quote").Range("C1").End(xlDown).Row
lastdtyperow = dataentry.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row
lastdqtyrow = dataentry.Range("C1").End(xlDown).Row
lastqtyperow = quote1.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
Set typ = dataentry.Range("B9:B" & lastdtyperow)
    
'this needs some work
Foot = Sheets("DATA VALIDATION").Range("I2").Value
    
'this is where the code for copying data begins
Dim i As Integer
Dim cell As Range
    
For i = 0 To lastdtyperow
    'copies types
    Set cell = dataentry.Range("B9").Offset(i, 0)
    If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
        quote1.Range("A13").Offset(i, 0) = cell.Value
        quote1.Range("A13").Offset(i, 0).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        quote1.Range("A13").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End If
    'copies quantities
    Set cell = dataentry.Range("C9").Offset(i, 0)
    If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
        quote1.Range("B13").Offset(i, 0) = cell.Value
        quote1.Range("B13").Offset(i, 0).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        quote1.Range("B13").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        quote1.Range("B13").Offset(i, 0).NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    End If
    'copies mfr
    Set cell = dataentry.Range("AB9").Offset(i, 0)
    If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
        quote1.Range("C13").Offset(i, 0) = cell.Value
        quote1.Range("C13").Offset(i, 0).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        quote1.Range("C13").Offset(i, 0).NumberFormat = "#,##0"
        quote1.Range("C13").Offset(i, 0).WrapText = True
        quote1.Range("C13").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End If
    'copies cat number
    Set cell = dataentry.Range("AC9").Offset(i, 0)
    If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
        quote1.Range("D13").Offset(i, 0) = cell.Value
        quote1.Range("D13").Offset(i, 0).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        quote1.Range("D13").Offset(i, 0).WrapText = True
        quote1.Range("D13").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter        
    End If
    'copies notes
    Set cell = dataentry.Range("AD9").Offset(i, 0)
    If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
        quote1.Range("E13").Offset(i, 0) = cell.Value
        quote1.Range("E13").Offset(i, 0).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End If
    'copies prices
    Set cell = dataentry.Range("AJ9").Offset(i, 0)
    If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
        quote1.Range("F13").Offset(i, 0) = cell.Value
        quote1.Range("F13").Offset(i, 0).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        quote1.Range("F13").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        quote1.Range("F13").Offset(i, 0).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
        quote1.Range("F13").Offset(i, 0).Font.Bold = False
    End If
Next i
```

The `For i = 0` is my copying loop that is not working as intended.

This code is my "control" for subsequent code. It determines if `i` needs to increase and the process be repeated. Once it hits the last cell with data in column B on dataentry, the code is supposed to stop and move to the next portion of sheet generation.

I tried changing the range of `lastdtyperow`, change `xlDown` to `xlUp` and other various odds and ends. If anything, changing ranges and `xldown`/`xlup` made the issue worse where it would stop even sooner and some changes caused Excel to lock up/crash.

Comment: Side note, but do you really have the letter `o` in `For i = o To lastdtyperow`? Main note: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) for how to find the last row. Then use a `For Each` loop and loop over each cell, instead of using `Offset`.

Comment: Whoops. That was a typo from just before I copied the code over. That has been corrected. I will test this your response and see what happens!

Comment: Your code is missing information. `i` could "stop incrementing" for many reasons, and none of them can be diagnosed from just the code you supplied. Include the relevant declarations and keywords in the code instead of telling us your real code has them! we're not seeing the declaration for that `lastdtyperow` variable (is it `Long` or `Integer`, or is it not declared anywhere at all?); does your real code say `On Error Resume Next` anywhere? If so, remove that end [edit] with the actual error you're getting (Overflow?).

Comment: That said finding the last row is usually more reliable with `lastdtyperow = dataentry.Range("B" & dataentry.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`.

Comment: @BigBen gah, copy-pasta got me again

Comment: I will edit and supply the full code, but its a doozy. I have not fully fleshed out my coding for breaking things apart into their own modules and such as of yet.

Comment: The idea isn't to get the full code, but a [mcve] that produces the same problem and is useful to other people looking for a solution to a similar problem - see [ask] for more details.

Comment: Fair enough. I will edit that back down :)

Comment: `Dim i As Integer` declares `i` as a 16-bit signed integer type; if you have more than 32,767 rows then when `i` gets assigned to 32,768 you get run-time error 6 "overflow" ...unless `On Error Resume Next` is hiding that bug - then `i` would "stick" to 32,767 and stop incrementing - which sounds like the problem you're describing. What is the value of `i` when execution stops? Have you tried setting breakpoints (F9) and stepping through the code line by line (F8) to see if everything is as expected?

Comment: Yes, as I step through the lines the code runs flawlessly until ```i``` hits either 8 or 9 (I can run it again if that is super important), it stops increasing like there is no more data and the code moves to the next step. My actually data set ends at row 250 and what we use it for, should never get close to or go beyond that.

Comment: Whats the value of ```lastdtyperow```?

Comment: @Warcupine, i just ran it again and ```lastdtyperow``` topped out at 8 as well, which would explain why ```i``` stops increasing. so second assumption that the problem laid with ```lastdtyperow``` seems to be right. I would like to add that I do not get an error, it just stops at 8 and data that should be copied does not get copied.

Comment: Try this instead of what you have ```lastdtyperow = dataentry.Cells(dataentry.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row```

Comment: @Warcupine that worked in the sense that it continued and grabed the rest of the data, however now it does not stop until it 250 and copies every line. This my be because those particular cells have formulas in them that are returning zeroes. The formulas go all the way down to row 250 are are =IF(ISBLANK(Counts!A6),"",Counts!A6). Is the fact those formulas are they is why it continued even though the cells are technically blank?

Comment: Are they all formulas and you want to ignore blanks or do you want to ignore the formula part? Yes it will pick up formulas as they are technically not empty cells.

Comment: Every cell in the relevant range ```dataentry B9-250``` has that formula in it tying it to the other sheet in the workbook. I would need it to ignore formulas that are not returning any value (as they should not return a zero due to the ```ISBLANK``` if im not mistaken)

Comment: I added to my answer to address that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this:

> i just ran it again and lastdtyperow topped out at 8 as well, which
> would explain why i stops increasing. so second assumption that the
> problem laid with lastdtyperow seems to be right. I would like to add
> that I do not get an error, it just stops at 8 and data that should be
> copied does not get copied.

– Tmyers

Your code is not grabbing the real last row. Using `Range("B1").end(xldown)` is pretty unpredictable. It will stop at any empty row (formulas and whitespace will be picked up) and it looks like it also stops after table headers.

A better approach is to use `.cells` instead of `.range` and also `xlup` instead of `xldown`.

```
lastdtyperow = dataentry.Cells(dataentry.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
```

Should grab the proper last row.

Don't forget to use proper referencing in front of `.Rows` or else it will use the active sheet. Or use a with:

```
With dataentry
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
end with
```

As mentioned by Mathieu Guindon in comments don't declare as `integer` instead use `long` There is actually no benefit to `integer` in VBA just always use `long`.

If you want to get only cells with a value that also have a formula you can use something like this:

```
dataentry.Columns("B").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

Or add in an `if` in the loop to ignore `cell.value = ""`

Comment: Worked wonderfully! I just need to make some tweaks to correct the overall base and it should work flawlessly.